# Sum a range of cells above the active cell, the range of cells is spaced over 3 columns

Tags: excel

After I clear all data below the last row with data, I offset to an active cell.
The active cell will be in column I, could be anywhere in column I.
I want to sum all the data above the active cell in the range from columns G, H & I.

Then put the total sum in the active cell. Not sure how to loop through this if anyone can help that would be great! Thanks.

```
Range("I" & cells(Rows.Count, "I").End(xlUp).row).Select

ActiveCell.Offset(3, 0).Select
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Sub Test()

   Dim lCurRow  As Long
   
   'Locates the last FILLED Cell in I and saves row number!
   lCurRow = Range("I" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

   'Place formula one row down       Formula Creation
   Cells(lCurRow + 1, "I").Formula = "=Sum(I" & lCurRow & ":G1)"

End Sub
```

All done w/o selects.

HTH

Comment: This does work thank you for taking the time to look into it. I was hoping however to have the total placed in the active cell instead of right beneath the data but that's okay. Thank You.

Comment: Using ActiveCell is a bad idea as you don't always know where the user is when the code is run. If you have a specific place you want the data I'd suggest naming that cell and then use Range("CellName").Formula = ...